# MySQL: Need help for query in my case

Tags: mysql

My company has application that installed on client desktop. The application will send data to server for each software that runs on the installed desktop as **total_click**. I want to know how many clicks for certain software filtered by date range.

The problem is, the application will always carry 'total_click' value (and each client carries different **total_click**). For example, in day 1 software A have 10 click, and in the next day, software A that runs only once will send 11 **total_click** to server. So, to get valid data of total click on day 2, I need to substract total click on day 2 with total click on day 1. I know it's confusing but it's also hard for me to explain the problem.

## Table Structure Example

```
ms_client  
- [PK]client_id (int)  
  
ms_software  
- [PK]software_id (int)
  
ms_click
- [PK]click_id (int)
- [FK]client_id (int)
- [FK]software_id (int)
- date (date)
- total_click (int)
```

## Table Data Example

**ms_click**

```
Click_ID    Client_ID    Software_ID    Total_Click    Date
1           1            1                      100    01/04/2015
2           2            1                       10    01/04/2015
3           3            1                     1000    01/04/2015
  
4           1            1                      120    02/04/2015
5           2            1                       20    02/04/2015

6           2            1                       40    03/04/2015
7           3            1                     1100    03/04/2015

4           1            1                      150    04/04/2015
5           2            1                       50    04/04/2015
5           3            1                     1200    04/04/2015
```

As you can see, it's easy to get **total_click** between 1 April and 4 April. All I have to do is *SUM* **total_click** on 4 April and subtract it with *SUM* **total_click** on 1 April.

But how can I get **total_click** between 1 April and 2 April? In 2 April, **client_id** 3 is not send any data therefore if I subtract *SUM* **total_click**' on 2 April with *SUM* **total_click** on 1 April it will return minus result (based on the data example, it should return 30).

Once again, sorry if it's confusing. And thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you expect the query output to be? Your description is confusing in that it alludes to the aggregate `SUM()` but also to subtraction between dates. `SUM()` would normally be applied without any subtraction, limiting dates with `BETWEEN` in the `WHERE`

Comment: From the example of data above, the valid result from  'SUM()' total_click between 1 April and 2 April is **30**, the valid result from 1 April and 3 April is **130** and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `total_click` for a given (`client_id`, `application_id`) never decreases, you can determine the effective click numbers on a per-client and per-application basis like so:

```
select client_id, software_id, MAX(total_click) as total_click
from ms_click
where date <= $target_date
group by client_id, software_id
```

You can use that to get the most recent `total_clicks` report as of each date of the boundary range, and take the difference:

```
select
  to_stats.client_id,
  to_stats.software_id,
  to_stats.total_click - coalesce(from_stats.total_click, 0)
from (
    select client_id, software_id, MAX(total_click) as total_click
    from ms_click
    where date <= $from_date
    group by client_id, software_id
  ) to_stats
  left join (
    select client_id, software_id, MAX(total_click) as total_click
    from ms_click
    where date <= $to_date
    group by client_id, software_id
  ) from_stats
    on from_stats.client_id = to_stats.client_id
      and from_stats.software_id = to_stats.software_id
```

The `LEFT JOIN` (and the `COALESCE()` in the outer select list) accounts for the possibility that there may be no click reports for some software prior to the "from" date (which is interpreted as 0).  Of course, you need to feed the particular "to" and "from" dates of interest to the query.

Comment: Wow, it works! Thanks a lot! The query takes 2-3 minutes though (ms_click has 1-2 million rows), but I think I can fix it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking for but my guess is:

```
SELECT t.*, COALESCE(t.total_click-MAX(t1.Total_Click),t.total_click) as clicks
FROM ms_click t 
LEFT JOIN ms_click t1
ON t.client_id=t1.client_id
  AND t.`date`>t1.`date`
GROUP BY t.client_id, t.`date`
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d7c5/1